# What is the use of having a g at the end of the regex in javascript?

Tags: regex

I am using a regex in jquery  to filter only numbers.

```
var regex = /^[0-9]*$/
```

What is the difference between the above and  `/^[0-9]*$/g`

Comment: In your case, `g` is not required. It is _global_ match flag, used to get all the matches. Without this flag, only first match is returned

Comment: @nu11p01n73R You mean _irrelevant_, right?

Comment: @Xufox yes, sorry for the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is one of the regular expression flags, which means global search, matched all the result in text.

Your question is the difference between the `/^[0-9]*$/` and  `/^[0-9]*$/g`

There is **no difference** in this specific case, because you want to filter only numbers, so whether you use flag 'g' or not, it would scan the whole string, return false if it has other characters.

But I can show you the difference between using flag 'g' or not in other case, like this:

```
var str = "abcdefgabcdefg";
var reg1 = /abcd/;
var reg2 = /abcd/g;
str.match(reg1);  //output is ["abcd"]
str.match(reg2);  //output is ["abcd", "abcd"]
```

There are some others flags like m, i, y. You can find the document [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 0):

The g modifier is used to perform a global match (find all matches rather than stopping after the first match).

```
var str = "Is this all there is?";
var patt1 = /is/g;
var result = str.match(patt1);
```

**Output:**
is,is

Note: Is th**is** all there **is**?

It will avoid first 'Is'.

Comment: Note: that first “is” is not the capitalized “Is”, but it comes from the word “this” (just to reduce confusion).